# jScrollPane not showing up using '.ui-autocomplete'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-jscrollpane

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/dmsrY/38/) is the fiddle. I am trying to make the jQuery UI AutoComplete have a jScrollPane scrollbar. For some reason unknown, the scrollbar shows up as the default scrollbar for macs.

JavaScript (just for the scrollbar):

```
$('.ui-autocomplete').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: true
});
```

I should tell you that I have in fact linked the document to the jScrollPane codes.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because everytime you type something the `.ui-autocomplete` element will be created new. So you have to add the jScrollPane every time it opens the drop down:

```
$('#input').autocomplete({
    source: langs,
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.ui-autocomplete').jScrollPane({
            showArrows: true
        });
    }
});
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: There seem to be a couple of errors in your code, jsFiddle is driving me crazy right now.

Comment: One of them is the `}` on line 7 should be `};`

Comment: Oh...I see just a `}` on line 7. Another one is that you nested the `({` wrong on line 1. On line 8, it should be `});` instead of `)};`

Comment: ah, wait, i looked at line 8... in line 7 the `;` is not neccessary because it is only an entry in an array. Your last suggestion is right. I will change this.

Comment: It seems that when you open it, the scrollbar shows up, but if you click out and open it again, it's gone. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/dmsrY/40/)

Comment: ¿hola? ¿are you still there?

Comment: I am trying to figure out why this happens but I have no idea. Maybe Google can help...

Comment: Maybe the `open: ...` part means that it happens when you open it 1 time.

Comment: No, open is called everytime you tipe into the text input.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35865/discussion-between-jjp-and-user2433059)